# Javascripts Regex. Find important Words and Name in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find important words and name in string.

1. Names (**Jon Dew**)
2. All capital words (mean important) like: **FBI**
3. Should not find word after .,?, ! ect except if it's a name, it mean two or more words with Capital like a name: **Jon Dew** or long important (**National String Instrument Corporation**) 4 words with capital letter is obvious that's it's a important name.

I have this regex, not bad but it do not exclude words after a dot, questions mark ect. but should accept name who start after a dot ect.

```
\B.\s(([A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*\s)?[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*)\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/TSjtMp/2

Comment: What if the sentence is *"**Trump** said that he has no intentions of..."* - By your rationale, Trump would not be highlighted. Is that correct? There's no fool-proof method of determining what is/isn't a name by checking capitalization. Your method of "Two capitalized words at the beginning of a sentence" gets you closer, but the method still has obvious limitations.

Comment: Yes, Important words begin with a Capital letter. except if it's after dot or question mark because it's impossible to know if it's a important word or not.

Comment: So it should find words in all-caps (making the assumption it is an acronym) and two consecutive capitalized words (making the assumption that it is a name?

Comment: He's the POTUS, so regardless of whether you like him or not, seems pretty important to me.

Comment: What are the expected results for the sample text you shared in the fiddle? Please also check [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/Ttz2xJ/2).

Comment: In my Regex101.com example, it should not find words like "The" who begin with Capital letter after a dot, question mark, exclamation ect... (impossible to know if it's important except if it followed with 2 or more words with Capital letters), should find acronym, two or more words like "National String Instrument Corporation" it's clearly important words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like a big comment than an answer, but posting this as an answer since I can have better format.

Using your exact regex, I can come up with the discard regex technique.
Since, it is actually "impossible" to know if a word is important or not after a dot, for instance "Trump" or "They" you can actually create a pattern like this:

```
discard patt1 | discard patt2 | discard pattN | (capture this)
```

[image]

The idea is to have a chain of patterns that you don't want, but the last pattern is actually what you want, then you have to grap the content from the capturing group. For instance:

```
A|The|This|(\b(?:[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*\s)?[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*\b)
```

In below link you can see an example of this idea:

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/TSjtMp/4)**

You can use patterns to discard the words you don't want, in above example I'm just discard patterns having `A`, `The`, `This`. This is just an idea, since if you have `Theodore` it won't be "important", but at least you can define your patterns for discard.

Comment: I agree that Federico Piazza has the best approach -- I have tried this before in a different scenario.

The best you can do is to provide a list of words that are exceptions to the 'Important' rule that you can check against.

Unfortunately this becomes a very big list -- you need to consider: However, Notwithstanding, (Un)fortunately, First(ly), Consequently, Honestly...  I could go on and on.

But it is a smaller list than the dictionary you would need to define all 'Important' words - (and it would still never be enough).

Comment: I saw that it do not find 3 Words and more like: National String Instrument Corporation

Comment: @Gino, that's because of your regex pattern. I didn't change your regex, just provided information about the discard technique